# Как при помощи функции поменять значение указателя?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, дерево

Есть структура узлов дерева:

```
   struct Node{
        int data;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
   };
```

Есть функция вставки, которая принимает указатель на указатель узла, а также значение

```
void _add(Node** ptr, int value)
```

Я пытаюсь использовать двойной указатель, чтобы изменить значение, на которое указывает указатель ptr. То есть: ptr указывает на root, который первоначально пуст. Функция это проверяет\находит и говорит:

```
*ptr = new Node();
(*ptr)->data = value;
```

Данная реализация не работает. Помогите пожалуйста. Скорее всего, я неправильно понимаю двойные указатели.

Comment: Сложность состоит в том, что _root является приватным полем класса Tree. Я пытаюсь реализовать рекурсивную функцию внутри класса Tree, поэтому использую двойной указатель

Comment: покажите вызов функции. Что именно не работает?

Comment: Если вы работаете "*внутри класса Tree*", то `private` мешать никак не должно. Давайте [ваш код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), без этого говорить не о чем.

Comment: Если функция `_add` объявлена в глобальном пространстве имён, то программа ill-formed, т.к. идентификаторы, начинающиеся с `_`, зарезервированы.